# What is output of this program? and Why?

Tags: c

Want this program will be output "Digi" but why it's output "Dig)tal Bangladesh".

Can anyone explain?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char str[120]="Digital Bangladesh";
int n;
n=strlen(str);
printf("%d \n",n);
str[4]="\0";
printf("%s",str);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"\0"` is a string. That should be `'\0'`, which is a NUL character.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Learning how to debug your code can be very educational.

Comment: Many many thanks. Problem solved <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have given basic explanation in the comments and improved your code a little (replaced `"\0"` with `'\0'` and included `string.h` for `strlen()`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[120] = "Digital Bangladesh";
    int n = strlen(str);  // can combine declaration and assignment into a single statement; 
                          // this will assign the actual length of string str to n
    printf("%d \n", n);
    str[4] = '\0';      // shouldn't be "\0" since anything in double quotes will be a string and not a character
                        // you are assigning 5th character (4th index + 1) of str to NULL ('\0') terminator character; 
                        // now str will have content "Digi"
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow!! Many Many Thanks for the code, I am a beginner so sorry all for if anything else